# Handle AWS EC2 Traffic Peaks

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 instance running on AWS Free Tier on the Bitnami LAMP stack. During traffic peaks, the application becomes extremely slow due to large number of mySQL connections.

I receive these peaks very less frequently, but I still want to be able to handle them well, and don't have a problem paying for a better AWS instance as well.

What is the best practice to deal with this?

Comment: If you cannot pay for a better AWS instance I would look to see which queries are the most resource intense and add that query to your question as this one is a little too broad.

Comment: Hey @DavidLee - I am willing to pay for a better instance. There are actually a lot many queries that are throwing a lot of data. Keeping the query optimisation aside, is upgrading the instance the best way to solve this? Any tips on upgrading?

Comment: Given you are keeping the query optimization aside your best option is to scale the application via hardware.  Again without seeing your queries it would be hard to determine whether the bottleneck is long CPU processing times or an overflow of application requests.

Comment: You need to look into caching, at the data layer (Redis) and at the HTTP response layer with a CDN like CloudFront or Cloudflare.